# Is it possible to make $c^* c^*$ gauge invariant?

Tags: gauge-invariance, second-quantization

Consider a (fermionic) second-quantized lattice model. We know that we can make $c^*(r')c(r)$ gauge-invariant by applying Peierl substitution, i.e.,
$$
c^*(r') \exp(iA_{r'r})c(r)
$$
so that if $c^*(r)\mapsto c^*(r) \exp(-i\chi(r))$, then the above formula maps to that with vector potential $A_{r'r}\mapsto A_{r'r} -(\chi_{r'} -\chi_r)$.

This seems impossible to do in the case of $c^* (r')c^*(r)$ (is it?). If so, how are external fields introduced into a superconducting Hamiltonian, i.e. a Hamiltonian of the form $c^*c +c^*c^* +cc$, so that the Hamiltonian is gauge-invariant?

Answer (score 1):

The superconducting Hamiltonian is gauge invariant if you assume the superconducting order parameter $\Delta$ to be a complex number carrying a fase factor $e^{i\phi(r,t)}$. The gauge transformation now involves a shift of both the vector potential $\bf{A}(r,t) \to \bf{A}'(r,t)$ and the phase $\phi(r,t) \to \phi'(r,t)$.

Notice how the introduction of a dynamical phase of the order parameter is essential to give a fully consistent (gauge invariant) theory. This is interesting because if you "integrate out" the phase variable, you get an effective theory for the electromagnetic field in the superconductor and you exactly recover London's equations.

Comment: Are there any references related to your answer? I would be very interested in the details of such formulation, i.e., what do you mean be "integrate out" and how can we recover the London's equations.

Comment: Sure! I have studied these things on Altland and Simons "Condensed matter field theory". This topic is covered in chapter 6. However this is not entry level and it took me a while to understand the details; but unfortunately I don't know any other reference